# Remove string contained within a specific starting and ending string

Tags: php, regex

I simply want to remove the whole substring from a string when the substiring starts with "StringA" and ends with "/r".

FX original string:

```
"PeterStringAnone/rGriffin"
```

should be

```
"PeterGriffin"
```

Comment: You don't have to do that with regex necessarily

Comment: Yes, I just added it because I guess it could also be done with regex.

Comment: Well, yes, it can be done with regex.

Comment: `preg_replace('~StringA(.*)/r~U', '', $str)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Demo](http://regex101.com/r/nS0rH1)

```
$re = '/StringA[\w\d]+\/r/';
$str = 'PeterStringAnone/rGriffin'; 
$result = preg_replace($re, '', $str);
```

Comment: Accepting yours since it is the is similar to the rest and it also has a demo. I hope I am not unfair to the rest :)

Answer (score 3):

You should test this :

```
$pattern = "(.*)StringA.*/r(.*)";
$replacement = "$1$2";
$string = "PeterStringAnone/rGriffin";
$new_string = preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $string);
```

I hope it will help you.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the following.

```
$text = 'PeterStringAnone/rGriffin';
$text = preg_replace('~StringA.*/r~i', '', $text);
echo $text; //=> "PeterGriffin"
```

If you will have multiple cases of this, follow `.*` with a `?` for a *non-greedy* match.

```
$text = preg_replace('~StringA.*?/r~i', '', $text);
```